# AVR I/O: DIgital vs Analog Input Programming

Tags: avr, atmel

I'm trying to use some previously developed sw from Github and ran across an interesting bit of sw coding.

He's using an Atmel ATtiny45 with digital I/O's on most of the PortB pins but PB3 is used as an analog (AtoD) input from an external potentiometer.
In his code, he's got the following snippet:

```
  if(PINB & MANCLK){
       PORTB |= CLKOUT;
       } else {
       PORTB &= ~CLKOUT;
       }
    }
```

(Note: 'CLKOUT' is a digital output pin.)

"MANCLK" is the analog input pin at PB3 so, what does the line: "if(PINB & MANCLK)..." do?
Does it actually consider all analog values coming in on that pin so, anything less than 2.5V is considered a logic low and anything over 2.5V is a high or, is this even a valid statement?
Is 'MANCLK' simply to be considered as a "0" or a "1"?
Not sure where to find good information on this particular situation.

Thanks for any help provided.

Regards,
Grant

[update] Here's the code....

`

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <avr/io.h>
 #include <avr/interrupt.h>
 #include <avr/sleep.h>
 #if !defined(TIMSK)
 #define TIMSK               TIMSK0
 #endif
 #if !defined(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
 #define TIMER0_COMPA_vect   TIM0_COMPA_vect
 #endif

// 100 us per tick
#define COUNT   199
#define TPSC    (1<<CS01)

#define AUTO    (1<<PB0)    //Pin5, MOSI and EN (via RN33 Pins 4&5).
 High = Enable
#define RUN     (1<<PB1)    //Pin6, MISO and ~HLT (via RN33 Pins 3&6).
 Low = Halt
#define MANCLK  (1<<PB3)    //Pin2, Analog input, Manual Clock Speed
 Setting (via potentiometer RV1)
#define CLKOUT  (1<<PB4)    //Pin3, CLK output
#define AUTOINT (1<<PCINT0)
#define RUNINT  (1<<PCINT1)
#define CLKINT  (1<<PCINT2)

#define MANDLY  500

volatile uint16_t count;
volatile uint8_t trigger;
volatile uint8_t manual;

uint16_t maxcnt;

void stopTimer(void) {
    PORTB &= ~CLKOUT;       // Clock output low
    TCCR0B &= ~TPSC;
    TCNT0;
    count = 0;
    trigger = 0;
}

void startTimer(void) {
    PCMSK = 0;
    TCCR0B |= TPSC;
}

void halt(void) {
    cli();
    stopTimer();
    PCMSK = RUNINT|AUTOINT;
    sei();

    sleep_enable();
    while(!(PINB & RUN)) sleep_cpu();
    sleep_disable();

    cli();
    startTimer();
    sei();
}

void manclk(void) {
    cli();
    stopTimer();
    PCMSK = CLKINT|RUNINT|AUTOINT;
    sei();

    while(!(PINB & AUTO)) {
        if(PINB & RUN) {
            if(PINB & MANCLK) {
                PORTB |= CLKOUT;
                } else {
                PORTB &= ~CLKOUT;
                }
        }
        sleep_enable();
        sleep_cpu();
        sleep_disable();
    }

    cli();
    startTimer();
    sei();
}

int main(void)
{
   DDRB = CLKOUT;
   PORTB &= ~CLKOUT;

   cli();
   TCCR0A = 0;
   TCCR0B = 0;
   TCNT0 = 0;
   TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
   OCR0A = COUNT;          // Interrupts every 100us when Timer running
   TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01);  // Timer Start /8 pre-scaler
   TIMSK |= (1 << OCIE0A);
   GIMSK |= (1 << PCIE);
   sei();

   // Setup the ADC
   //ADMUX |= (1 << MUX1); // Only using ADC2 (original)
   ADMUX |= (1 << MUX0) | (1 << MUX1);   //new code - MUX Select ADC3 @
    PB3
   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);
   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1); // 125 kHz ADC clock

   //Enable Sleeping
   set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_IDLE);

   while (1) {

//if RUN = HLT = Low ==> HALT
       if (!(PINB & RUN)) {
           halt();
           continue;
       }

//if AUTO = ENABLE = Low ==> manclk...if AUTO (ENABLE) == LOW ==>
 MANCLK
       if (!(PINB & AUTO)) {
           manclk();
           continue;
       }

       ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
       while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));
       maxcnt = 5000 / (64 - ADC/16);

       if (trigger) {#
           PORTB ^= CLKOUT;
           trigger = 0;
       }

       sleep_enable();
       sleep_cpu();
       sleep_disable();
   }

   return 0; // never reached
   }

   ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
       count++;
       if (count >= maxcnt) {
           count = 0;
           trigger = 1;
       }

}

EMPTY_INTERRUPT(PCINT0_vect);`
```

Comment: `PINB` and `PORTB` are defined in the `avr/io.h`, but could you please post the actual lines of code that define `MANCLK` and `CLKOUT` so we can figure out what the code does?  (You said "MANCLK" is "PB3" but that doesn't fill me with a lot of confidence; I'd rather see the code.)

Comment: Hi...not sure how to add in my code...I tried to but kept getting a "code not formatted correctly" error.

Comment: I posted a detailed answer below.  If it satisfactorily answers your question, would you mind clicking the green checkmark to accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we expand some of the preprocessor macros, your code becomes easier to explain:

```
if (PINB & (1 << 3))
{
  PORTB |= (1 << 4);
}
else
{
  PORTB &= ~(1 << 4);
}
```

Now just looking at the code above we can tell that it does the following: it reads bit 3 of the PINB register and if it is 1, it sets bit 4 of the PORTB register to 1.  Otherwise, it clears (sets to 0) bit 4 of the PORTB register.

If you don't understand why this is true, I recommend that you look up the definitions of the following C bitwise logic operators in a C book or C tutorial: `&` `|`, `<<`, `|=`, `&=`.

A simpler way of describing the code is that it copies the value from bit 3 of PINB to bit 4 of PORTB.

Now to get a better understanding of what the code does, you need to find the **ATtiny45 datasheet** and read the definitions of the PINB and PORTB registers.  Then you will discover the following:

1. Reading bit 3 of PINB is how you do a **digital reading** of PB3.  It does not use the ADC and it does not have a super accurate threshold like you were thinking.  The thresholds are defined somewhere in the "Electrical Specifications" section of the datasheet or similar.
2. Since bit 4 of DDRB is 1 in your program, PB4 is configured as a **digital output**.  Therefore, writing a value to bit 4 of PORTB is how we set the output value of PB4.  Writing a 0 to it makes it drive low (0 V), and writing a 1 to it makes it drive high.

In summary, this is some pretty basic AVR code that does a digital reading and writes that value to a digital output.